# Internet Explorer and Firefox debugger and multiple version tester

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox

I am using IETester to test multiple versions. Is there a tool to debug script errors for Internet Explorer?

Similarly, is there an equivalent tool for Firefox for checking multiple versions in one box, like IETester?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [this Internet Explorer developer toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en).

Also, [Visual Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio) apparently lets you do script debugging in your browser, if you have it.

You also asked about testing multiple versions of Firefox. Portable Firefox might be a good idea. It will allow you to install multiple versions simultaneously without spending too much time setting up profiles for them. It has versions for Firefox 1, 1.5, 2, and 3 - look under [legacy versions](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable#legacy) low down here.

Answer (score 2):

I use [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) to manage multiple environments with different browser versions.

On Linux it's easy enough to run multiple versions of Firefox side-by-side (here's [an example](http://olex.openlogic.com/wazi/2008/running-multiple-firefox-versions-side-by-side/)) but I imagine you're on Windows, so VirtualBox is my suggestion. =^)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell exactly what you're talking about, but I would recommend [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) for debugging in Firefox.

Comment: Looks like the OP was wanting a similar debugging tool for IE.

Answer (score 0):

[Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com/) is one of the best JavaScript debugging tools. However, it is only available for Firefox. I believe the [Internet Explorer 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8) beta comes packaged with some web developer tools, but I've not used them and can not comment on their quality or usefulness.

In terms of checking your sites rendering in different engines, I find the [IE Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/1419) Firefox plugin very useful for quickly checking my layout in [Internet Explorer 7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_7).